# How to use MTA API with laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I want to use MTA API (Metropolitan Transportation Authority ) service. But when I send a request it will return one file. How can I get data from MTA API?

http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=MYAPIKEY&feed_id=26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install [guzzlehttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) package for `laravel` using `composer`,

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

use it's namespace in your controller:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Then you can simply do,

```
$client = new Client();
$api_response = $client->get('http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=MYAPIKEY&feed_id=26');
$response = json_decode($api_response);

// do your stuff with the response
```

Comment: But its give me blank array in response